# How to pass an array of arrays to a DLL and get back an array of arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, dll

I have an array of arrays that is dynamically allocated in my C++ code. I want to pass it to a function exposed by a DLL (let's suppose the function is called `myfunction()`). Then the DLL will perform some calculations and will return an array of arrays.

At the moment, I'm using `std::vector` in my code, and I could do something like `std::vector<std::vector element>> myfunction (std::vector<std::vector<element>> array_of_array)`, but I would like to avoid passing `std::vector`s to the DLL since I know I can get in trouble with that.

What is the safest mode to do this? Could you please point me to a sample code?

Comment: Would using Boost.Multiarray be a solution? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: If the array is rectangular and I had control of the code for the DLL I'd pass a 1D array and appropriate stride information so that the DLL can use it like a 2D array. Much easier to deal with that arrays of arrays and often a lot faster due to contiguous memory.

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your comments. Each array in my array is a list of point coordinates (3 coordinates for each point), therefore I think it's rectangular. How could I achieve what you're suggesting me regarding the stride information? Do you know a place where I can find sample code?

Comment: For sure the use of boost could be a valid alternative, thank you. However I'd like trying  not to use external libraries to do this

Comment: An array is rectangular if the columns are always the same length. Since your case is always three, you don't even need to pass that information on. Accessing the data is always `array[row * 3 + column]`. You should see huge performance gains because the CPU can make great use of cache (unless your algorithm hops around through the array randomly).

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I was not precise enough. With my last comment I meant that the situation should be like this: std::vector<std:vector<element>>, where element is for example an array of three doubles that are the three coordinates of a point. The problem is that I do not know the size of the std::vector<std:vector<element>> that I pass to the function and the size of the std::vector<std:vector<element>> that the function will return